# Need to update list item and then put it in textfile

Tags: c#, linq

So I am doing this c# program which basically is a coffee machine. Asks the user to register and adds the instance in a textfile, then login, then asks which coffee he wants from a provided list, and finally increments a property named "coffee points". The problem is that I have no idea how I am going to update the coffee points inside my textfile. I can get the coffee points and increment them by 1 and then print them in console, however, I dont know how to update just the coffee points in my textfile of a certain user.

Below is the code I am using to retrieve the coffee points of the logged in user and increment them by 1, and store them in the variable "newCoffeePoints".

```
int newCoffeePoints = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < customerList.Count; i++)
{
    if (customerList[i].iUsername == cu2.iUsername)
    {
        customerList[i].iCoffeePoints += 1;
        newCoffeePoints = customerList[i].iCoffeePoints;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are about to find out why people like databases - they abstract away the concept of persistent storage, presenting an API that makes sense to an application.  First you need to decide on a format for your "text file" (consider XML or JSON - they both have APIs that make "serialization" easy).  Then, you need to consider whether you are going to keep the "text file" up to date after every transaction, or if you want to periodically keep things in sync, or whether you want to read the file when you start, and save it when you end.

Comment: it's just a school assignment that I'm working on; nothing special

Comment: The easiest way to do this is 1) use XML or JSON with a standard _serialization_ API, 2) to read the file in as the application starts, _deserializing_ into your "objects", 3) operate only on the objects within the normal operation of the program, and 4) _serialize_ your objects back out to XML or JSON, overwriting the file as you exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for this exact purpose we have so many different types of databases such as Mongo, SQL etc.

But if you're trying to serialize/deserialize object and save it to a file among other types of serialization you might want to consider JSON format. The libarary [Newtonsoft.js](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is what we (C# developers) usually use for that.

You could create a virtual structure that reflects what you need.
Since we might want to find object by key a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` collection suits much better than `List<T>`.

Do whatever operation you need to do with users in a `Dictionary<key, value>` and then serialize it to JSON and save it to disc using the `File.WriteAllText(json)` method.

Whether to do it after each update (so that if app crashes all the data is saved) or do it once when the app is about to finish execution will depend on your needs.

The field with dictionary could be something along the lines of:

```
// CKeyType here is a type of customer's id field such as int, string etc.
private static readonly CustomerDict = new Dictionary<CKeyType, Customer>();
```

Comment: Thanks.. I will do that ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem by using JSON and Newtonsoft Library. (Fabjan mentioned above)

Here is a tutorial link from Microsoft Virtual Academy that you can follow.

https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/introduction-to-json-with-c-12742?l=xxtX274UB_8805494542